# How to properly type the _document.tsx file from Next.js?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I got most of this code from the official docs example on how to work with `styled-components`:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js

But the example uses `.js` and I'm using Typescript.

I'm getting some type errors and warning and I'm not sure how to properly type it. I've already solved part of the problem. This is what I'm still missing:

---

**Error 1:** What should be the full signature type or the return type for the `static async getInitialProps(ctx)` function? What is the type for the `ctx` parameter?

[image]

---

**Error 2:** Unsafe access on `ctx.renderPage`. I guess this will be fixed once I properly type the `getInitialProps` function

[image]

---

**Error 3:** This is also probably related to the missing type for `getInitialProps`

[image]

---

```
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
          sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
      });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }

  render(): ReactElement {
    return(
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          // SOMETHING IN THE HEAD
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is what I've ended up doing to type the `getInitialProps` and `render` methods:

```
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import Document, { DocumentInitialProps, DocumentContext } from 'next/document';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext): Promise<DocumentInitialProps> {
    // ...
  }

  render(): ReactElement {
    return(
      // ...
    );
  }

}
```

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js

Full `styled-components` example:

```
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript, DocumentInitialProps, DocumentContext } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

// NEXT.JS CUSTOM DOCUMENT
// https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext): Promise<DocumentInitialProps> {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
          sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
      });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: [
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ],
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }

  render(): ReactElement {
    return(
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          // SOME HEAD ELEMENTS
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. 

The only issue is as there is no default return for the `getInitialProps` function, it was giving me this error - `Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.ts(2366)`. Had to solve it by adding a default return statement at the end (after the finally block)- `return {} as DocumentInitialProps`. 

Hope this also helps.

Comment: It does not like `styles: ( <> ... </> )` and throws a TS Error:

Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactFragment | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>[] | undefined'.ts(2322)

Comment: Found the solution: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/36008#issuecomment-1094073787

Comment: I've updated the answer according to @Tobi comment here above. Now `styles: ( <> ... </> )` is `styles: [ <> ... </> ]`.

Comment: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. If you want to avoid it you can do `styles: [ <React.Fragment key="some-key"> ... </React.Fragment>`. Where some-key can be whatever makes sense to you.

Answer (score 22):

Sharing my version of making _*document.tsx* typescript compatible especially when you are using Material UI with emotion.

_*document.tsx*

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Document, {
  Html,
  Head,
  Main,
  NextScript,
  DocumentContext,
  DocumentInitialProps,
} from 'next/document'
import createEmotionServer from '@emotion/server/create-instance'
import { theme, createEmotionCache } from '@theme'
import { AppType } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/utils'
import { EmotionCache } from '@emotion/cache'

interface DocumentProps extends DocumentInitialProps {
  emotionStyleTags: React.ReactNode[]
}

const MyDocument = (props: DocumentProps) => {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head>
        {/* PWA primary color */}
        <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
        />
        {/* Inject MUI styles first to match with the prepend: true configuration. */}
        {props.emotionStyleTags}
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with static-site generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (
  ctx: DocumentContext
): Promise<DocumentProps> => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

  // You can consider sharing the same emotion cache between all the SSR requests to speed up performance.
  // However, be aware that it can have global side effects.
  const cache = createEmotionCache()
  const { extractCriticalToChunks } = createEmotionServer(cache)

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (
        App: AppType | React.ComponentType<{ emotionCache: EmotionCache }>
      ) =>
        function EnhanceApp(props) {
          return <App emotionCache={cache} {...props} />
        },
    })

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
  // This is important. It prevents emotion to render invalid HTML.
  // See https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/26561#issuecomment-855286153
  const emotionStyles = extractCriticalToChunks(initialProps.html)
  const emotionStyleTags = emotionStyles.styles.map((style) => (
    <style
      data-emotion={`${style.key} ${style.ids.join(' ')}`}
      key={style.key}
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style.css }}
    />
  ))

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    emotionStyleTags,
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

*theme.ts*

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors'

// Create a theme instance.
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#556cd6',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
  },
})

export default theme
```

*createEmotionCache.ts*

```
import createCache from '@emotion/cache'

// prepend: true moves MUI styles to the top of the <head> so they're loaded first.
// It allows developers to easily override MUI styles with other styling solutions, like CSS modules.
export default function createEmotionCache() {
  return createCache({ key: 'css', prepend: true })
}
```

Comment: I've been banging my head against this for hours. Thanks!

Comment: This really should be the top answer. Its the most concise and it truly shows what you need to convert to Typescript for MUI cache. Thanks shet_tayyy you saved me a LOT of time!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to import the `DocumentContext` type from `next/document`.

For example

```js
import Document, {DocumentContext} from 'next/document';

class MyDoc extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return initialProps;
  }
  render() {}
}
```

To learn more, read here https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document.

Comment: Thanks. And what about the return type?

Comment: It should be Promise<DocumentInitialProps>. Remember to import it from next/document

Answer (score 2):

They actually have it typed in [lib/shared/utils.ts](https://github.dev/vercel/next.js/blob/d4a3c66479f6ea48c958c663067800d5e3fecf21/packages/next/src/shared/lib/utils.ts#L24-L25). Unfortunately, while they exported the `AppType` right next to it in `next/app`, `DocumentType` is never exported at top level for some reasons.

Tested in Next 12 - 13, you may use the type like this:

```
import type { DocumentType } from "next/dist/shared/lib/utils";

const Document: DocumentType = (props) => <>{...}</>;
```

Answer (score 2):

For `styled-components`:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import Document, {
  Html,
  Head,
  Main,
  NextScript,
  DocumentContext,
} from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export async function getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

  try {
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: App => (props: React.ComponentProps<any>) =>
          sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
      })

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return {
      ...initialProps,
      styles: [initialProps.styles, sheet.getStyleElement()],
    }
  } finally {
    sheet.seal()
  }
}

export default function MyDocument() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```